# Can you have a Facebook Like button for a whole site and/or for individual product pages?

Tags: facebook, web-applications

I know this is borderline StackOverflow question, but since a lot of user will have installed Facebook Like buttons, I thought it was a good place to ask.

I want to add a little Facebook Like button on my site, with the little counter showing how many people like this. I'm simply wondering if I can choose to have the counter site-wide (count all the Likes across all pages) or have the counter individual for each page.

Thanks.

As a side question: what do you think is better.?

- Like buttons with more impressive number but all linking to the same (home) page...
- Like buttons with smaller count, but (facebook stream) linking to different pages...

Answer (score 0):

every page that has a FB widget can be linked to an FB page... therefore the possibilities are endless... if you want every page to additively connect to just one FB page, then just make sure that each embedded widget points to the same FB page...